# Salesforce Authenticator gives me a six digit code but Salesforce website asks for a two word phrase?

Tags: mfa

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I downloaded the Salesforce Authenticator app to my phone and linked my Salesforce work account. The authenticator gives me six digit codes and the website requests two word phrases. I tried using the codes but they don't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for a two-word phrase that means the authenticator has not been set up for the account or the salesforce admin might have removed it and you need to setup it up again.

To set up the authenticator you can follow these steps: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.salesforce_authenticator_add_account.htm&type=5

Once the authenticator is set up, you would be able to approve logins or use the 6-digit code. Let me know if this helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using the 'Add an Account' button in the Salesforce Authenticator App on my mobile phone to add a new Account. In that process, I got a two word phrase rather than a 6 digit code.

Another note: Prior to pressing the 'Add an Account' button in the Salesforce Authenticator app on my phone, I deleted an old Account that I had in that app, which had stopped working for some reason.